# get the View at the position X of a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

How can I retrieve the View at the position X in a ListView? I dont want to inflate a new one, just retrieve the cell visible in the screen for change some parameters programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a dirty solution:

1. You should be able of identify each row generated. For example adding a TextView with visibility=gone and writing a unique value there when generating (or recycling the row)
2. In the listactivity call to getListView.setSelection(position) to the desired cell
3. Survey the listview list for the row (until displayed)

   ```
   lv=getListView();
   for (int i=0;i <lv.getChildCount();i++){
      if (((TextView)lv.findViewById(R.id.my_hidden_textview)).getText.equals(mykey)){
      // view found
      } else {
      // schedule another survey "soon"
      }
    }
   ```

   For the schedule you can use something like:

   ```
   final int RETRY_DELAY=100;
   new Handler(){
       public void handleMessage(Message msg){
          if (msg.what<0) return; //something went wrong and retries expired
                  lv=getListView();
          for (int i=0;i <lv.getChildCount();i++){
            if (((TextView)lv.findViewById(R.id.my_hidden_textview)).getText.equals(mykey)){
               //result = lv.findViewById(R.id.my_hidden_textview);
            } else {
               this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what-1,RETRY_DELAY);
            }
          }     
       }
   }.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(10,RETRY_DELAY);
   ```

As I said is a very ugly solution but it works

Answer (score 2):

Since views in ListView are re-used/re-cycled. There is no direct way of getting a view reference from the ListView.

If you want to access a view you need to extend `ArrayAdapter` and then override `getView`. There you should call the `super.getView` and write your own custom code.

If we you really need to control more than try extending `BaseAdapter` or `CursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clearly understand your problem. But to what I've understood I would suggest you use a frame layout within a linear layout. You can use another frame layout to do your manipulations.